# multiple switches for same case

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I have this code:

```
switch(month){
    case 1:
        System.out.print("January");
            break;
case 2:
    System.out.print("February");
        break;
case 3:
    System.out.print("March");
        break;
case 4:
    System.out.print("April");
        break;
case 5:
    System.out.print("May");
        break;
case 6:
    System.out.print("June");
        break;
case 7:
    System.out.print("July");
        break;
case 8:
    System.out.print("August");
        break;
case 9:
    System.out.print("September");
        break;
case 10:
    System.out.print("October");
        break;
case 11:
    System.out.print("November");
        break;
case 12:
    System.out.print("December");
        break;
}
```

Okay so this code works 100% perfectly... for the int month. I have another int (avgMonth) which can only hold the same values(1-12) and I want to only have the same outputs (the months). How can I add avgMonth to this code without have to copy my whole switch and case?
I tried use commas (month, avgMonth) and &&'s (month && avgMonth) and also +'s (month + avgMonth) but to no avail.

Comment: Well, call the same method containing this horrible switch statement. Why don't you create a Month enum, containing a number and a name?

Comment: Ouch, my eyes, you can do that in two lines of code (or less)

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is your friend

Comment: I'd advise against using a switch/case for this at all... use an array or a collection.

Comment: really? How because this is taking up so much lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encapsulate the whole block of code in a method, and pass `avgMonth` and `month` as parameters. Like this:

```
public static void monthNumToName(int month) {
    // … same as before
}
```

Alternatively, you could simplify the code using a `Map`:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> months;
static {
    months.put(1, "January");
    months.put(2, "February");
    months.put(3, "March");
    months.put(4, "April");
    months.put(5, "May");
    months.put(6, "June");
    months.put(7, "July");
    months.put(8, "August");
    months.put(9, "September");
    months.put(10, "October");
    months.put(11, "November");
    months.put(12, "December");
}

public static void monthNumToName(int month) {
    String name = months.get(month);
    if (name == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month number: " + month);
    System.out.print(name);
}
```

Or *even simpler*, just use an array, because we know beforehand that month numbers are restricted in the range 1-12:

```
private static final String[] months = {
    "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
};

public static void monthNumToName(int month) {
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month number: " + month);
    System.out.print(months[month-1]);
}
```

Anyway, when you need to print the name of the month do this:

```
monthNumToName(month);
monthNumToName(avgMonth);
```

Comment: Change return type from `void` to `String` and add `return name;` as the last line.

Comment: How to I make it print on the same line? I'll put the code in the question

Comment: @user3250237 I didn't notice that it was printing in the same line. There, I fixed my answer - just replace `println` with `print`

Answer (score 2):

A simple Array could do the job, like

```
String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

then your month would be like

```
monthName = monthNames[month - 1];
avgMonthName = monthNames[avgmonth - 1];
```

Comment: when month = 1 it out puts March

Comment: you're right. It should be '-' instead of '+' in the array's index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html), which have a [`getMonths()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getMonths%28%29) method.

> Gets month strings. For example: "January", "February", etc.

```
public static String getMonth(int month){
    return new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.UK).getMonths()[month-1];       
}
```

- I did `month-1` because you want 1 to be mapped with January
- You may add some checks for the bounds of the array returned by `getMonths()`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
private static String[] MONTHS = "none,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December".split(",");
public static void printMonth(int month) {
     System.out.print(MONTHS[month]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, delete that `switch` and pretend that you never wrote something so goddam ugly.

Now that you have a clean slate, create a `enum`:

```
public enum Month {

    JANUARY(1),
    FEBRUARY(2),
    //other months
    ;

    private static final Map<Integer, Month> LOOKUP;

    static {
        final Map<Integer, Month> lookup = new HashMap<>();
        for (final Month month : values()) {
            lookup.put(month.number, month);
        }
        LOOKUP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(lookup);
    }

    public static Month fromNumber(final int num) {
        final Month month = LOOKUP.get(num);
        if(month == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No month for number " + num);
        return month;
    }

    private final int number;

    private Month(final int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final String name = name();
        return name.substring(0, 1) + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

}
```

And use it like so

```
final Month month = Month.fromNumber(someInt);
```

In order to print the month you can just to:

```
System.out.println(month);
```

And the `toString` method will covert it to sentence case.